# Locked my phone with "find my device" and can't open it

Tags: security, google, password, nokia

I have seen this question several times but have not found an answer helpful to me. I am new to Stack Overflow and cannot comment, so I am going to ask it again. I just copied someone who asked the same question with a few changes.

I have a new phone (Nokia C110), but it's locked from Google's "Find My Device". I locked it because I lost the phone, then I recovered it. I lost the "Find my device" password. Once you lock it the password field disappears off the app and there is no way to put a different password in or delete the old. Is there any way to unlock my phone without erasing the data?

P.S. I must have spent 6 hours today searching for an answer. Half were about how to do a factory reset  because google locks the phone so tightly you have to go through hell even to do that! It won't let me go to settings, I don't have a pattern lock or camera on the main screen, and the google log in screen doesn't come up when I start so all of those solutions are out. Like one of the other folks who asked the question, I didn't have any password on it originally.

Comment: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6160491?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Changan, but looked at this link earlier, it does not say how to change or take off the "secure device" password after you put it on.